# hasManyThrough laravel relation

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have three table below.

```
+-----------------+   +---------------------+   +-------------+ 
|    products     |   |  product_countries  |   |  countries  |
+-----------------+   +---------------------+   +-------------+ 
|   id            |   |  id                 |   |   id        |
|   name          |   |  product_id         |   |   name      |
|   description   |   |  country_code       |   |   code      |
+-----------------+   |  other columns      |   +-------------+
                      +---------------------+
```

**hasManyThrough** in Country::class model to get all products.

```
public function products()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Product',
        'App\ProductCountry',
        'product_id', // Foreign key on feeds table...
        'id', // Foreign key on articles table...
        'code', // Local key on users table...
        'country_code' // Local key on feeds table...
    );
}
```

I want products which are related to countries or one country:

```
$user = \App\Models\Country::find(1);
dd($user->products);
```

Comment: I think your relationship is [many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relation you're describing best suits a many to many, which is usually written in Laravel as a *belongsToMany* on both sides.

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function countries()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Country::class);
    }
}

class Country extends Model
{
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class);
    }
}
```

If you stick to Laravel's naming conventions:

- Rename `product_countries` to `country_product`.
- In `country_product` use `country_id` instead of `country_code`.

...you should be able to access the relations in the way you expect:

```
$country = \App\Models\Country::find(1);
dd($country->products);

$countries = \App\Models\Country::with('products')->where(...)->get();
foreach ($countries as $country) {
    dd($country->products);
}
```

If you don't want to stick to the conventions, you are able to customise how you define the relationships. See [Laravel's documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) for further details.

---

In your case, to specify your relations using your custom table name and the custom field names you can do this:

```
// In your Product model
return $this->belongsToMany(Country::class, 'product_countries', 'country_code', 'product_id');

// In your Country model
return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'product_countries', 'product_id', 'country_code');
```

Comment: yes and thank's for answering..but i have to used country code in relation...i don't know why is this not working relation is correct..but it's shown onthing

Comment: I would definitely recommend changing the relation to use `id` instead of `country_code`, it makes things much easier to work with. If you don't want to, check out the documentation on how to specify the pivot table name and custom column names if you really want to stick with `country_code`

Comment: See my updated answer for how to use a custom table name and custom field names.

Comment: yes it's Many-To-Many relation.i made stupid mistake

Answer (score 1):

[Many-to-many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) is the correct model relationship. You need to add your custom table name in the second argument if not Eloquent will automatically create for you in alphabetical order (like `country_product`). You don't need to create `ProductCountry` Model because it is only a Pivot table.

You didn't post your migration file, (just by guessing), the recommended is using `country_id` but if you use the `country_code`/`product_id` as foreign keys you need to add it also in the arguments as well as in your migration file like this (also check the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many))

```
 $table->foreign('product_id')->references('id')->on('products');
 $table->foreign('country_code')->references('code')->on('countries');
```

Try this one...

In your Product model

```
class Product extends Model
{
   public function countries()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Country','product_countries','product_id','country_code');
   }
}
```

In your Country model

```
class Country extends Model
{
   public function products()
   {
      return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product','product_countries','country_code','product_id');
   }
}
```

In your controller

```
use App\Country;

$products = Country::find(1)->products()->get(); //finding by id or

$products = Country::where('country_code',$value)->with('products')->get(); //finding by code
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe nor realy link to the question but in this example, how do you do to show the "other columns" in a collection ?
I have the same model and I will use this in a ressource like this :

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => (string)$this->id,
        'type' => 'team',
        'attributes' => [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'status'=> $this->status,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ],
        'relationships' => $this->when(!$request->is('*/users*') && count($this->users) > 0,[
            'user' => [
                'data' => UserResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('users')),
            ]
        ])
    ];
}
```

and the UserRessouce is this :

```
public function toArray($request)
{
    return [
        'id' => (string)$this->id,
        'type' => 'user',
        'attributes' => [
            'name' => $this->name,
            'email'=> $this->email,
            'created_at' => $this->created_at,
            'updated_at' => $this->updated_at,
        ],
        'relationships' => $this->when(!$request->is('*/teams*') && count($this->teams) > 0,[
            'team' => [
                'data' => TeamResource::collection($this->whenLoaded('teams')),
            ]
        ])
    ];
}
```

The json result :

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": "2",
        "type": "team",
        "attributes": {
            "name": "Kassulke and Sons",
            "status": "open",
            "created_at": "2022-04-08T12:13:32.000000Z",
            "updated_at": "2022-04-08T12:13:32.000000Z"
        },
        "relationships": {
            "user": {
                "data": [
                    {
                        "id": "1",
                        "type": "user",
                        "attributes": {
                            "name": "John Doe",
                            "email": "john Doe",
                            "created_at": "2022-04-08T12:13:50.000000Z",
                            "updated_at": "2022-04-08T12:13:50.000000Z"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

in the "middel" table between Team and user I have "more colums" like "role" and I will show this in the relation.